# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

HTML:

```
<body> 
<div id="main"> 
<span id="msg">Are you sure you want to proceed?</span><br><br> 
<input type=button id="Yes" value="Yes"> 
<input type=button id="No" value="No"> 
</div> 
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function doTask(){...}
function doNothing(){...}
var do=function(){doTask();}
var nothing=function(){doNothing();}
document.getELementById("Yes").addEventListener("click",do);
document.getELementById("No").addEventListener("click",nothing);
```

When i run the document, the console shows the Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error on the document.getElementById("Yes")... line. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: why do you assign the function doTask() to the var do as another funtion?

Comment: Looks like you have misspelled getELementById() ?

Comment: `getELementById` Your L is a captital letter.

Comment: do is a keyword in javascript  while...do... you cant redefine it

Comment: oops. i corrected the typo and it shows "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' I wrote this just for the question. I dont use do in my original script.

Comment: why dont you post your original script ?????????????

Comment: Your javascripts may be executed before the HTML code is rendered.

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' The original script is a lot of lines. So i just posted the important parts.

Comment: man i mean the important lines in origin form ok ;))

Answer (score 0):

why not like this ?

> document.getElementById("Yes").addEventListener("click",doTask());
>   document.getElementById("No").addEventListener("click",doNothing());

Comment: Typo `getELementById`- no big `L`.

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
document.getElementById("Yes").addEventListener("click",do,false);
document.getElementById("No").addEventListener("click",nothing,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `getElementById` in place of `getELementById`

```
   document.getElementById("Yes").addEventListener("click",do);
    document.getElementById("No").addEventListener("click",nothing);
```

and you can also use

```
<input type=button id="Yes" value="Yes" onClick="doTask();"> 
<input type=button id="No" value="No"  onClick="doNothing();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried by replacing `L` with `l` from `getELementById()` and `do` with `don` (just a variable name). Worked fine for me.

```
function doTask(){alert('Yes');}
function doNothing(){alert('No');}
var don=function(){doTask();};
var nothing=function(){doNothing();};
document.getElementById("Yes").addEventListener("click",don);
document.getElementById("No").addEventListener("click",nothing);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmalh/QK4qY/)